# cmd command not running within java program

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am trying to run a cmd command. Everything works fine but no output.  I don't understand why.
***UPDATED CODE***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class CmdTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String command=   "ffmpeg -i D:\\test%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 outfile.avi";
        Process process;
        System.out.println("first stmt");
        try
        {
             process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
             Scanner kb = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
             System.out.println("try block");
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("last stmt");
    }
}
```

I am expecting execution of cmd command mentioned above.  Nothing is going wrong during compilation and execution.  However, command not executing write.

Comment: What output are you expecting...?

Comment: Please be more specific - what isn't working as expected? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: try adding `process.waitFor();` Also read from error stream as well.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc i am expecting execution of cmd command mentioned above but nothing going wrong during compilation and execution but command not executing write

Comment: Also verify ffmpeg is in your system path.

Comment: Running an external process in java is quirky. See http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code should give error because the line `Scanner kb = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());` will not see process. `process` is defined inside `try-catch`.

Secondly, have you tried `ffmpeg -i D:\\test%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 outfile.avi` on `command window`? If not, try it.

Third, instead of running that command try running some easy commands like `dir`, `pwd` etc.

Fourth, put some `System.out.println("say something")` inside the code, then you would be able to see where it fails/stops.

Comment: first, sory but its was not giving any error sir
second, i have tried the code in cmd its working fine
third, i have tried them they are working fine
fourth. ihave updated codes according to your sugesstion but nthing going right....

Comment: I copied and run your code, it prints out `first stmt\n try block\n last stmt`. If you are getting the print outs, then the problem is related to `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Try this one as well, `command = cmd.exe /C start ffmpeg -i D:\\test%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 outfile.avi;`. I had a working `ffmpeg` command, I tried it and it worked. When you say `cmd.exe /C start`, java opens a `cmd` and runs your command in `command window`

Comment: nthinbg working fine sir i have considered your suggestion but nor ouput

Comment: have you tried running `hello world program`? or run something like `System.out.println(x+y);`. if this is not working either, then you have problem with java. otherwise, this program is working. I runned and tested

Comment: You are welcome. but if you solved with my help, please accept my answer as correct answer by clicking the tick under vote for my answer.